# Role user laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, session-variables

I use this code in my controller LOGIN and they are role type in my database: $users->isAdmin() $users->isOwner() $users->isMember()

```
public function dologin(Request $request){
    $users = new Users;
    $email = $request->input('u_email');
    $password = $users->setPasswordAttribute($request->input('pwd1'));
    //get user id from email
    $user_id = $users->get_user_from_email($email);
    foreach($user_id as $u){
      $u_type = $u->u_type;
    }
    // Check validation
    if (auth()->attempt(['u_email' => $email, 'password' => $password] )){
        if($users->isAdmin() == $u_type){
          return redirect('admin');
        }
        if($users->isOwner() == $u_type){

        }
        if($users->isMember() == $u_type){

        }
    }else{

    }
  }
```

Code in Users Model

```
public function isAdmin(){
        return 0 ;
    }
    public function isOwner(){
        return 1 ;
    }
    public function isMember(){
        return 2;
    }
```

My question: 
-how to store role in session for logged in dashboard?
-how to declare in controller this role

Thanks you for all help

Note: the role type are integer 0, 1 and 2. I don't use enum type in my database for this role but integer

Comment: Methods called `isOwner`, `isAdmin`, `isMember` should return boolean values or be called something else. Makes your code much clearer.

Comment: this is code in users model
public function isAdmin(){
        return 0 ;
    }
    public function isOwner(){
        return 1 ;
    }
    public function isMember(){
        return 2;
    }

Comment: Your approach is indeed wrong. You can use single method `getRole` to return role of your user or have these methods return true or false according to role of your user.

Comment: how to use this method with my code?

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but a side note to help you with writing more understandable code.

Answer (score 0):

To use session in pages, make sure at the start of the page you have `session_start();` (before any HTML tag).

After that, when he is logging in and everything is allright set `$_SESSION["u_type"]=$u_type;` and you can refer to it until you destroy your session.

To check in dashboard if he is admin, owner or member just check

```
//don't forget session_start(); at the begging of your file
if($_SESSION["u_type"]==0)
//admin
else if($_SESSION["u_type"]==1)
//owner
else if($_SESSION["u_type"]==2)
//member
```